# Birt Engine with multiple requests

Tags: java, birt

I am using the BIRT engine to generate reports. The report is running fine with no problem but when I stress test the report (for example run the report 10 times by different users), I get a `NullPointerException` on the line :

```
factory.createReportEngine(config);
```

And sometimes it cause a different exception on query build.

So could any one advise me on the problem of BIRT engine with concurrent requests? and how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BIRT engine supports very well many concurrent requests, but we must not create this "IReportEngine" object on each report, as it seems you do.

This method:

```
factory.createReportEngine(config);
```

should be invoked once for all when the engine is initialized, and then you can store the resulting IReportEngine object in a static property of your class for example. Furthermore the method which is initializing the engine should be synchronized.

Thus all report requests can use it and you won't have troubles anymore with stress tests .

**EDIT:** This also works in a cluster context, each node of the cluster has its own BIRT engine. For example if there are 3 nodes in the cluster (3 JVM), it results in 3 static BIRT engines. Though it is still important to initialize each engine in a "synchronized" method, because me must ensure two process won't invoke simultaneously factory.createReportEngine **in a same JVM**.

Comment: Thanks Dom for your reply :) may be initializing the report engine once is a good for enhancement but the Synchronized will not work with me as the report is running in a cluster environment

Comment: A cluster context should not be a problem, i edited the answer